# HTML Email - Text responsive based on device

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email, email-templates

I have an email template, that works perfect but I'm looking to enhance it.
Currently, the nav at the top of the email has 4 columns of text. In order for it to look good on both desktop and mobile, the font needs to be size 13. This prevents any weird line breaks on mobile and keeps the nav in one line.

Is it possible to have let's say the nav on desktop be size 16, and then if a user is on mobile device, the font scales down to 13?

See screenshot below. I believe this may possible with media queries and CSS?

Thank you all in advance for any assistance!

Trying to have big font for text on desktop, and have that same text scale down on mobile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can.

I prefer a mobile-first approach because Gmail IMAP (one version of Gmail) doesn't support `<style>` blocks, and desktops generally do (or with some very old systems they'll still be on one line but be small).

To do that, have your mobile style inline, and then use a min-width media query with an Outlook alternative for desktops (Outlook desktop Windows doesn't support media queries, but does have inbuilt alternatives).

```
<style>@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .changeText {font-size:16px !important;}
}
</style>
<p class="changeText" style="font-size:13px;mso-ansi-font-size:16px;">
  <a href="...">Link 1</a> &nbsp; 
  <a href="...">Link 2</a> &nbsp; 
  <a href="...">Link 3</a> &nbsp; 
  <a href="...">Link 4</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi nathan, thank you for that insight! Will take that to the shop and see if I can get it working.